# Perl sound synthesis on Debian 9

Tags: debian, audio, perl

How to generate sounds in Perl on Debian 9?

Own research done, not much found. Eg. [Audio::NoiseGen](https://metacpan.org/pod/Audio::NoiseGen), which has problems with dependencies (namely [Audio::PortAudio](https://metacpan.org/pod/Audio::PortAudio), which in turn is old and doesn't accept `portaudio-2.0` on my Debian 9).

I mean sound synthesis, not playing files. The closest to what I'm looking for is using the `system` command to call the `sox` program. But that's reaching outside of Perl, so not a good integration. And I need a good one like a Perl module.

Comment: As for moving this question to SE, I've already posted there and got lots of close votes without a relevant answer.

Comment: As I believe I commented over on SO, see [this PerlMonks thread](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1203062), where it sounded like it might be worth taking a look at [`SDL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/SDL/lib/pods/SDL.pod).

Comment: @haukex Thanks. But I skimmed through SDL's manual and didn't find a word about synthsis. There was only audio playback there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

audio is just a curve, so code which makes a point wobble up and down and is sampled at some interval of time will synthesize audio (raw audio in PCM format) ... here perl generates such a curve

```
perl -e 'for ($c=0; $c<4*44100; $c++) {
             $k=1*sin((1500+$c/16e1)*$c*22e-6); print pack "f", $k;
         } ' |
sox -V -r 44100 -c 1 -b 32 -e floating-point -t raw - \
    -c 2 -b 16 -t wav - trim 0 3 gain -1 dither |
tee test.wav |
aplay
```

output from perl is piped into sox which effectively just adds a wav format header to the PCM audio ... then the wav file is piped into tee which outputs a wav file while piping to aplay which renders the audio ... for the benefit of others this installs needed debian (ubuntu) packages

```
sudo apt-get install sox alsa-utils
```

now just save above code into a file and source it ... vi somefile-with-above-code

```
source somefile-with-above-code
```

its handy to separate the process of audio synthesis from its sonic rendering so above division of labor is often justified

Alternatively you can use perl to synthesize the raw audio and dump it directly to a file yourself ... just save following perl snippet into a file  `vi my-audio-perl-file`

```
perl -e 'for ($c=0; $c<4*44100; $c++) {
             $k=1*sin((1500+$c/16e1)*$c*22e-6); print pack "f", $k;
         } '
```

then execute it redirecting output to a file using

```
source ./my-audio-perl-file  > synth_audio.pcm
```

then use [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) to visualize and render the PCM file ... File -> Import Raw Data

```
-> Encoding -> 32 bit float 
-> Byte order -> Little-endian
-> Channels  -> 1 Channel (Mono)
```

and hit `Import`